# How to mock an error inside a try block and catch it using Jest? just for a single test

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, integration-testing, supertest

I'm trying to test the catch block(see bellow) In my node.js application in one of the routes so I'm trying to cause an error inside the try block but from my test file:

```
router.post('/', [auth, validate(validateRental)], async (req, res) => {
  const customer = await Customer.findById(req.body.customerId);
  if (!customer) return res.status(400).send('Invalid customer.');

  const movie = await Movie.findById(req.body.movieId);
  if (!movie) return res.status(400).send('Invalid movie.');

  if (movie.numberInStock === 0) return res.status(400).send('Movie not in stock.');

  let rental = new Rental({ 
    customer: {
      _id: customer._id,
      name: customer.name, 
      phone: customer.phone
    },
    movie: {
      _id: movie._id,
      title: movie.title,
      dailyRentalRate: movie.dailyRentalRate
    }
  });

  try {
      await new Fawn.Task()
        .save('rentals', rental)
        .update('movies', { _id: movie._id }, {
            $inc: { numberInStock: -1 }
        })
        .run();

      res.send(rental);
  } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).send('Something Failed.');
  }
});
```

and in my test file where I'm using Jest, and supertest inside the postRental() function :

```
it('should return 500 if something failed', async () => {
    // want to create an error inside the try block to be catched so that res.status would be 500

    const res = await postRental();

    expect(res.status).toBe(500);
});
```

How can I make a clean test here and create an error in the try block only for this single test to pass ?